# Get BLAS implementation information from CMake

Tags: cmake, blas, intel-mkl, openblas

In a project I am using

```
find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)
```

to detect BLAS.

**Is there a way to tell which implementation of BLAS *was* found after this?**

According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBLAS.html) `BLA_VENDOR` can be used to require a certain implementation, but it doesn't report which one was found.

Unfortunatelly I need to know which BLAS was found because different implementations have subtle differences in their interfaces, for example MKL uses `zdotu` with 6 arguments rather than 5 (first is the pointer to the result value).

Comment: It seems that script [FindBLAS.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake) doesn't store information about BLAS provider. If you want to choose API usage between several cases, the most direct approach is to try all these cases with [try_compile](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/try_compile.html) or similar mechanisms. E.g. you may try compile a source file, which calls `zdotu` with 6 arguments. If it succeed, then you would know how to use this function.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks. It is a pity that FindBLAS gets that information and then throws it away.

Comment: @Tsyvarev the worst part of the interface difference is that it is not a matter of compiling or not it is a difference in the ABI. So it would be hard to even detect at runtime (it produces a segfault if you are lucky).

Comment: Actually, you may call `find_package(BLAS)` **several times**, with different `BLA_VENDOR`. So, once a call will succeed, you could be confident about the provider.  This approach could be simpler would `BLA_VENDOR` accept several vendors specification at once, but even single vendor per `find_package` call is usable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, that is a good trick. An extra complication is that one might need to try with every "mkl" version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Tsyvarev suggestion I ended up doing this

```
set(BLA_VENDOR Intel10_64lp)
find_package(BLAS)
if(BLAS_FOUND)
    message("MKL environment detected")
    add_definitions(-DRETURN_BY_STACK)
else()
    unset(BLA_VENDOR)
    find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)
endif()
```

It seems that `-DRETURN_BY_STACK` (or `-DFORTRAN_COMPLEX_FUNCTIONS_RETURN_VOID`) is a way recognized by *some* BLAS headers (e.g. `cblas.h`) to have MKL-compatible declarations.

Technically one might need to try with every variant of `intel` mkl BLAS, *and choose one somehow*, I am putting it here for completeness.

```
Intel10_32 (intel mkl v10 32 bit)
Intel10_64lp (intel mkl v10+ 64 bit, threaded code, lp64 model)
Intel10_64lp_seq (intel mkl v10+ 64 bit, sequential code, lp64 model)
Intel10_64ilp (intel mkl v10+ 64 bit, threaded code, ilp64 model)
Intel10_64ilp_seq (intel mkl v10+ 64 bit, sequential code, ilp64 model)
Intel
```